# Как правильно удалять элемент после того, как его анимация закончилась?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, css-animation

Есть плагин с динамическими окошками, при закрытии у них отыгрывается CSS3 анимация и... их надо убить, код выглядит как-то так:

```
$confirm.addClass('hide');
$confirm.remove();
```

Проблема в том, что окно сразу же удаляется и исчезает, как дать понять коду, что надо удалить элемент после того, как он скрылся? Раньше делал обычным `.fadeOut`, но сейчас анимация стала посложнее плавного затухания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример завершения css transition.

Список всех событий https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Источник http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end

```js
var myButton = $('#button'),
  myBox = $('#box');

myButton.click(function() {

  myBox.addClass('change-size');

  myBox.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
    function(e) {

      $('#msg').append('<p>Animation complete</p>');

      myBox.removeClass('change-size');

    });



});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: hotpink;
}
@keyframes growBox {
  to {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
.change-size {
  animation: growBox 3s linear 0s 1 normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.6/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="button" class="button">
    <p>Click Me</p>
  </div>

  <div id="box" class="box">
  </div>

  <div id="msg"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А если браузер не поддерживает анимации? Событие сработает?

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже люблю использовать CSS-анимации, а не JS, но в подобных случаях приходится постоянно городить костыли, маленькие или большие. 
Я знаю два способа решения проблемы. Обычно, я применяю первый, в силу его простоты и быстроты реализации. Хотя, несомненно, второй является более гибким и надежным.

**1 -** Простой и банальных хардкод. Если я делаю CSS-анимацию исчезновения элемента длительностью 600мс, я откладываю удаление элемента в таймаут на соответствующее время. Таким образом, в вашем случае:

```
$confirm.addClass('hide');
setTimeout(function(){
    $confirm.remove();
},600)
```

Проблема в том, что время задается в двух несвязанных местах. Если вы (или  другой прогер после вас) измените длительность CSS-анимаци, к примеру, логично полагая, что этого достаточно - получите неожиданный результат.

**2 -** повесить на элемент слушатель события "transitionend" и выполнять действия по окончании анимации. Зависимости от времени уже нет и есть гибкость. Но, в случае двусторонней анимации (как в примере, когда элемент может быть по окончании анимации как слева так и справа) следует внутри колбека также проверять состояние элемента, чтобы понять, "включились" мы или "выключились".
Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/1xz9by4o/
Пример использования:

```
$("#id").on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e){
//do semething
})
```